# Media|Player na área de notificação

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Bom, estou fazendo um `app` que tem um plugin `MediaPlayer` para tocar **rádio web**.

Gostaria de adicionar, quando o `player` fosse clicado, uma previa dele na *área de notificações* (Acho que é esse o nome) também como abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem que achei, o que eu desejo é que, no lugar onde está escrito "Leve Garoa, São Paulo", colocar o **player** da Rádio logo abaixo, quando eu, lá no `App`, clicar no **play**.

O **app** da Rádio **Gospel Mix** também faz isso.

A ideia é que quando o `App` fosse minimizado, o usuário tenha a experiência  de visualizar o *plugin* quando exibir a **área de notificação**.

Mas não apareceu o **player** na **área de notificação**.

Segue o **código**.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void notificacao (){

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.player);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home)
                    .setContentTitle("Rádio Capital")
                    //.setCustomContentView(remoteViews)
                    .setContentText("Agora deu");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, player.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(player.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```